# Postgres array - how to insert and ignore duplicate?

Tags: postgresql

I have a `text` array that's storing unique file urls.  Is there a way to insert a url and ignore duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing URLs that you want to be unique in a `text[]` array is a really bad idea, but since you asked.

```
update my_table
   set file_urls = file_urls||'new_file_url_here'
 where id = <id>
   and not 'new_file_url_here' = any(file_urls)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Yes I know :(